# Why I'm getting segmentation fault when I'm printing array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having problem with `SEGFAULT` when printing array with `printf` using `for` loop. Here's my source:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int a;
        int b[4];
        unsigned short i;
        scanf("%i", &a);
        for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
                b[i] = a % 10;
                a = a / 10;
        }
        for(i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
                printf("%i\n", b[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the fault in line 13:

```
13          printf("%i\n", b[i]);
```

Comment: Another way to fix your loop but still keep `i` unsigned is: `for (i = 4; i--; )`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, that's the canonical downwards-counting loop that keeps the semantics of C arrays (inclusive lower bound, exclusive upper bound). Very good. After all, it does make sense to use an unsigned variable as array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` has a type of `unsigned short`, but in your for loop:

```
for(i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
```

`i >= 0` will NEVER be false because `i` is unsigned.Just change `i` to a signed type:

```
int i;
```

and it would be fine.

Comment: +1 for int i because I'm unsure whether scanf("%i") will handle short variables properly. May result in overwriting low 16 bits of b pointer

Answer (score 2):

Since i is of `unsigned short int`, the second `for loop` will not terminate, `i`'s value will go on as:

```
3
2
1
0
65535
65534
65533
..
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared `unsigned short i`, so `i` is always `>= 0` and you never exit the loop.

Change `unsigned short i;` for `int i;`.

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop for printing an array b to this

```
for(i = 3; i > 0; i--){
    printf("%i\n", b[i]);
```

in your code **i >= 0** evaluates to true when i = 0 so **i--** is decrementing to 65535 and then it trys to access **b[65535]** which leads to invalid access.